# Why the standard output stream in java , namely "System.out" field, can be used though it is null objects?

Tags: java

Recently, I have been reading the java jdk source(version jdk 8). I read this code  `public final static PrintStream out = null;` , but I think System.out.println() can't take effect and even should cause compile-time error, because "System.out" is null value. That confuses me very long.

More details about java stream conception, and why that works.

Please, thanks you!!!!

Comment: Look further down https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L257

Comment: yes. That article help me, thank you!!